# High CPU usage on idle AMQ Artemis cluster, related to locks with shared-store HA

Tags: high-availability, activemq-artemis

I have AMQ Artemis cluster, shared-store HA (master-slave), 2.17.0.

I noticed that all my clusters (active servers only) that are idle (no one is using them) using from 10% to 20% of CPU, except one, which is using around 1% (totally normal). I started investigating...

Long story short - only one cluster has a completely normal CPU usage. The only difference I've managed to find that if I connect to that *normal cluster's* master node and attempt `telnet slave 61616` - it will show as connected. If I do the same in any other cluster (that has high CPU usage) - it will show as rejected.

In order to better understand what is happening, I enabled `DEBUG` logs in `instance/etc/logging.properties`. Here is what master node is spamming:

```
2021-05-07 13:54:31,857 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] Backup is not active, trying original connection configuration now.
2021-05-07 13:54:32,357 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] Trying reconnection attempt 0/1
2021-05-07 13:54:32,357 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] Trying to connect with connectorFactory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty$NettyConnectorFactory@6cf71172, connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=slave-connector, factory=org-apache-activemq-artemis-core-remoting-impl-netty-NettyConnectorFactory) ?trustStorePassword=****&port=61616&keyStorePassword=****&sslEnabled=true&host=slave-com&trustStorePath=/path/to/ssl/truststore-jks&keyStorePath=/path/to/ssl/keystore-jks
2021-05-07 13:54:32,357 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector] Connector NettyConnector [host=slave.com, port=61616, httpEnabled=false$ httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=true, useNio=true] using native epoll
2021-05-07 13:54:32,357 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] AMQ211002: Started EPOLL Netty Connector version 4.1.51.Final to slave.com:61616
2021-05-07 13:54:32,358 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector] Remote destination: slave.com/123.123.123.123:61616
2021-05-07 13:54:32,358 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.remoting.ssl.SSLContextFactory] Creating SSL context with configuration
trustStorePassword=****
port=61616
keyStorePassword=****
sslEnabled=true
host=slave.com
trustStorePath=/path/to/ssl/truststore.jks
keyStorePath=/path/to/ssl/keystore.jks
2021-05-07 13:54:32,448 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector] Added ActiveMQClientChannelHandler to Channel with id = 77c078c2
2021-05-07 13:54:32,448 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl] Connector towards NettyConnector [host=slave.com, port=61616, httpEnabled=false, httpUpgradeEnabled=false, useServlet=false, servletPath=/messaging/ActiveMQServlet, sslEnabled=true, useNio=true] failed
```

This is what slave is spamming:

```
2021-05-07 14:06:53,177 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] trying to lock position: 1
2021-05-07 14:06:53,178 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.FileLockNodeManager] failed to lock position: 1
```

If I attempt to telnet from master node to slave node (same if I do it from slave to slave):

```
[root@master]# telnet slave.com 61616
Trying 123.123.123.123...
telnet: connect to address 123.123.123.123: Connection refused
```

However if I attempt the same telnet in that the only working cluster, I can successfully "connect" from master to slave...

---

Here is what I suspect:

1. Master acquires lock in `instance/data/journal/server.lock`
2. Master keeps trying to connect to slave server
3. Slave unable to start, because it cannot acquire the same `server.lock` on shared storage.
4. Master uses high CPU because of such hard-trying to connect to slave, which is not *running*.

**What am I doing wrong?**

**EDIT**: This is how my NFS mounts look like (taken from `mount` command):

```
some_server:/some_dir on /path/to/artemis/instance/data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,sync,vers=4.1,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,acregmin=0,acregmax=0,acdirmin=0,acdirmax=0,soft,noac,proto=tcp,timeo=50,retrans=1,sec=sys,clientaddr=123.123.123.123,local_lock=none,addr=123.123.123.123)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out issue was in `broker.xml` configuration. In `static-connectors` I somehow decided to list only a "non-current server" (e.g. I have srv0 and srv1 - in srv0 I only added connector of srv1 and vice versa).

What it used to be (on 1st `master` node):

```
<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="abc">
        <connector-ref>srv0-connector</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>srv1-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

How it is now (on 1st `master` node):

```
<cluster-connections>
    <cluster-connection name="abc">
        <connector-ref>srv0-connector</connector-ref>
        <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
        <max-hops>1</max-hops>
        <static-connectors>
           <connector-ref>srv0-connector</connector-ref>
           <connector-ref>srv1-connector</connector-ref>
        </static-connectors>
    </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

After listing all cluster's nodes, the CPU normalized and it's not only ~1% on active node. The issue is totally not related AMQ Artemis connections spamming or file locks.